# Can I publicize ESSE in my geology apps for first courses students? What should I say in the ad if so?

Tags: discussion

I am publishing along 2023/24 a serie of guide plus quiz smartphones geology apps to do later a trivial videogame for first courses geology students.

I wonder if I can profit my apps serie to atract geology content to Earth Science Stack Exchange, wich is something I would like to see.
My users are gonna be mostly students of first courses and not geologists but some teachers might also see the hypothetical advertisement. The number of students that could see the ad in the next years is in the order of a few hundred thousands, as there are not a lot of geology apps in the marcket  in the present (for example [my mineral guide](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geologyapplications.minerals) is 5th for the search geology in spanish after investing only 200€ in publicity), the apps are going to be free with only a video ad each half an hour of use, the content is going to be cowrited or reviewed by my teachers, and I am going to invest in publicity until the apps are shown in the first entries of frequent searches in the store.

My fear is to atract only a lot of low quality students geology questions, lowering visibility to other Earth Sciences questions. I could also don't atract any geologist and the number of questions and answers need to be balanced to have a healthy site. Also, as the site has not a lot of geologists answering I migth neither nurture any user that could potentially become an answerer once they learn more knowledges in the University.

---

### How should I present the site if so?

I think I should start by something like *"We are writing a free Earth Sciences wonderfull library of knowledge and you are welcome to participate"*

I could say something positive about the editor and about the reputation system with moderation privileges earns.

A good thing of the site is also the posts profit the Earth Science Stack Exchange page rank to appear in Google searches. That could encourage teachers to share their knowledge.

[image]

**What else could I say atractive to the students and geologists that are going to install my apps?**

---

I am sure I must warn we do not allow id-my-rock questions, but that outcrops questions are more than welcome.

Also, I think I must warn we do not answer homework questions with no effort shown for the part of the student.

**What else should I warn to the students before posting their questions?**

---

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so [I asked it in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384540/should-i-publicize-the-earth-science-stack-exchange-site-in-my-geology-apps) and they say to feel free to insert the link.

I think I am not going to talk much more about the site in the ad. I think also it is better I put the ad in english in all languages as a minimum level of english is needed to participate.

[image]