# Tips for an advertisement of the site in a mineraology app

Tags: support

[My app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geology_quiz_and_guide.mineralogy) is in the 5 first results for mineralogy search in french, spanish, arabian and russian, has 3,5k users and is receiving 30 daily installs, but it can only atract mainly geology questions.

Please, can you give me some tips to help me elaborate a good advertisement?

I haven't published any ad yet.

Some things I have in mind:

- Put in the side menu "Ask a question" with a red icon (they will think they can ask about the minerals of the app).
- Say the true, that the forum is excelent but [is gonna die if no questions come](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2016/29779)., so it is us who are happy if they ask.
- The editor is excelent and accepts pictures of outcrops and geoforms.
- We have few, but some good geologists ansewering for free.
- Ask to name the forum to their teachers and graduated people so maybe we earn a bit of geologists answering also.